# First modal gets stuck after close of second modal

Tags: html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Please help, I can't find the problem. I really don't understand why my first modal get stuck after I close my second modal. I have a button which opens a "login" modal, inside that modal there's a link "conditions", which also open another modal, so basically a modal inside a modal. My login modal has a long content which I can scroll in it, after I close the conditions modal I cannot now scroll my login modal, unless I will close that modal and open again.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login-signup-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header pad-bottom0">
                .......
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>I agree to blahblah <a data-toggle="modal" href="#terms_and_condition">Terms and Condition</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                ......
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="terms_and_condition" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Terms and Condition</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                THE COMPANY
                <p>BLahblahblah</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

> **Multiple open modals not supported**
>
> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time
>   requires custom code.